# PHP MySQL PDO Binding Input/Output Same Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a simple MYSQL stored procedure I created like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20))
RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');
```

Now I created another PHP script to call the stored procedure.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$dsn = '***';
$user = '***';
$password = '****';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL hello(?)");
$value = 'Michael';
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $value\n";
```

According to the PHP documentation, adding the PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUPUT should set the INPUT/OUTPUT parameter flag, but this does not seem to be working.

I am expecting this output: procedure returned Hello Michael!

I am getting this output: procedure returned Michael

How can I bind a parameter that should be used for the input and then get replaced by the output of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a stored procedure. It's a stored function so it must be called like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT hello(?)");
```

I hope that helps!